# multicollinearity for one-hot encoding

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, data-science

Do we always need to remove a column for one-hot encoding to prevent multicollinearity?
In the solution here (https://www.kaggle.com/omarelgabry/titanic/a-journey-through-titanic/comments#138896) it mentions

> @Kevin Chang You need to delete one column of the dummy variables to
>   avoid the state of Multicollinearity. It's a state of very high
>   correlations among the columns(independent variables); meaning that
>   one can be predicted from the others. It is therefore, a type of
>   disturbance in the data, and if present in the data the statistical
>   conclusions made about the data may not be reliable.

In the solutions here, there is not catering for multicollinearity
https://www.kaggle.com/sharmasanthosh/allstate-claims-severity/exploratory-study-on-ml-algorithms

May I know is it a must, or in what situation we ned to cater that?

Answer (score 1):

If I have to answer your question `"Do we always need to remove a column for one-hot encoding to prevent multicollinearity?"`, the answer is yes.

The common way to prevent multicollinearity is to remove highly correlated predictors from the model. If you have two or more factors with a high VIF, remove one from the model. Because they supply redundant information, removing one of the correlated factors usually doesn't reduce the R-squared.

Or you could use Partial Least Squares Regression (PLS) or Principal Components Analysis, regression methods that cut the number of predictors to a smaller set of uncorrelated components.

Comment: This is not true in general. Decision tree models benefit from multi collinear variables. Parametric and semi-parametric models, however, using a regularizing factor such as Ridge, Lasso or ElasticNet, avoid the multicolinearity.